# Spark query hive cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have data in Cassandra where key (id) is in binary format, I am trying to do a query between hive table (which has the same id field as LongType). So, when I run this query in spark sql 2.0.1:

```
SELECT a.key
FROM cassandra_table a
WHERE a.key in(cast('829404561643414' as binary));
```

it returns me results in a fraction of seconds. Also, when I run this query the spark sql:

```
SELECT cast(cast(id AS string) as binary)
     FROM hive_table c LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (c.field) pixTable AS pix LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (pix.fieldList) olTable AS olc
     WHERE (c.hit_date_utc = 20161001) LIMIT 1;
```

it also returns me results in a fraction of seconds.

But when I do a subquery like this:

```
SELECT a.key
    FROM cassandra_table a
    WHERE a.key in(SELECT cast(cast(id AS string) as binary)
         FROM hive_table c LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (c.field) pixTable AS pix LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (pix.fieldList) olTable AS olc
         WHERE (c.hit_date_utc = 20161001) LIMIT 1);
```

It creates around 40,000 spark tasks and job just keep running.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Run an "Explain". It most likely is deciding that it can't push down the predicates.

Comment: @RussS +- *BroadcastHashJoin [key#4], [CAST(CAST(id AS `id` AS STRING) AS BINARY)#46], LeftSemi, BuildRight
   :- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@3cb472a2 sparksql_adtransactionlog.cassandra_table[key#4,col#5,val#6] ReadSchema: struct<key:binary,col:binary,val:binary>
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, binary, true]))
      +- *GlobalLimit 1
         +- Exchange SinglePartition
            +- *LocalLimit 1
               +- *Project [cast(cast(olc#44.conversion.id as string) as binary) AS CAST(CAST(id AS `id` AS STRING)

Comment: @Russ I don't see filters or predicate pushdown happening here. So, is there a way I can optimize my query. Also, I didnt understand how the similar query makes a difference: SELECT a.key
FROM cassandra_table a
WHERE a.key in(cast('829404561643414' as binary));